# Python: Continue if variable is an 'int' and has length >= 5

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that does some calculations with a user input number. I need a way to check if user entry is an integer and that entered number length is equal or more than 5 digits. If either one of conditions are False, return to entry. Here is what i got so far and its not working:

```
while True:
    stringset = raw_input("Enter number: ")
    if len(stringset)>=5 and isinstance(stringset, (int, long)):
        break
    else:
        print "Re-enter number: "
```

If anyone has a solution, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: `stringset.isdigit()`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not working for negatives though...

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hah! True. The only other way is to use a try-except.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would work

```
while True:
    number = input('enter your number: ')
    if len(number) >= 5 and number.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        print('re-enter number')
```

Comment: ... for positive integers

Comment: @M4HdYaR Luckily, it shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution

```
while True:
    stringset = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        number = int(stringset)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
    else:
        if len(stringset) >= 5:
            break
        else:
            print("Re-enter number")
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution here. `raw_input` could mention the fact that the number should be long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your code

```
while True:
        stringset = raw_input("Enter number: ")
        if len(stringset)>=5:
            try:
                 val = int(userInput)
                 break
             except ValueError:
             print "Re-enter number: 
        else:
            print "Re-enter number:
```

- Do not use isdigit function if you want negative numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

By default raw_input take string input and input take integer input.In order to get length of input number you can convert the number into string and then get length of it.

```
while True:
    stringset = input("Enter number: ")
    if len(str(stringset))>=5 and isinstance(stringset, (int, long)):
        break
    else:
        print "Re-enter number: "
```